# DropDownList - ASP.NET Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having trouble with a drop down list in my ASP site

Ok, what am i trying to do?

i want to select a item from my drop list and then fire some code, an example when i click Hek, it loads the correct information i'm after, when i click Dodixie after the page refreshes but not loading the new values, also when i click on a name the drop down text keeps defaulting to Jita again.

here is some code:

Front End:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="stationSelect" runat="server" CssClass="OverviewText" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="stationSelect_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem value="0">Jita</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="1">Hek</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">Dodxie</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="3"> Armar</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="4">Rens</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Back End:

```
protected void stationSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stationSelect.ClearSelection();
            stationSelect.SelectedIndex = stationSelect.Items.IndexOf(stationSelect.Items.FindByValue("0"));
            {
                string OrePriceA = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30002187";

                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(OrePriceA);

                TriPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 34, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                TriPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 34, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
                PyrPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 35, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                PyrPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 35, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
                MexPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 36, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                MexPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 36, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
                IsoPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 37, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                IsoPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 37, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
                NocPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 38, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                NocPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 38, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
                ZydPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 39, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                ZydPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 39, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
                MegPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 40, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                MegPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 40, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
                MorPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 11399, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
                MorPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 11399, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            };

            stationSelect.ClearSelection();
            stationSelect.SelectedIndex = stationSelect.Items.IndexOf(stationSelect.Items.FindByValue("1"));
            {
                string OrePriceH = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30003394";

                XmlDocument xdocH = new XmlDocument();
                xdocH.Load(OrePriceH);

                TriPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 34, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                TriPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 34, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
                PyrPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 35, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                PyrPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 35, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
                MexPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 36, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                MexPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 36, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
                IsoPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 37, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                IsoPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 37, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
                NocPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 38, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                NocPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 38, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
                ZydPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 39, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                ZydPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 39, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
                MegPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 40, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                MegPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 40, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
                MorPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 11399, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
                MorPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 11399, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            };

            stationSelect.ClearSelection();
            // ENTER TEXT HERE 
            {
                string OrePriceD = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30002659";

                XmlDocument xdocD = new XmlDocument();
                xdocD.Load(OrePriceD);

                TriPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 34, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                TriPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 34, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
                PyrPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 35, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                PyrPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 35, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
                MexPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 36, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                MexPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 36, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
                IsoPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 37, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                IsoPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 37, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
                NocPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 38, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                NocPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 38, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
                ZydPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 39, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                ZydPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 39, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
                MegPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 40, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                MegPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 40, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
                MorPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 11399, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
                MorPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 11399, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            };
            stationSelect.ClearSelection();
        }


        // Dodixie
        enum TranTypeD { Buy, Sell, All };
        enum StatTypeD { Volume, Avg, Max, Min, StdDev, Median, Percentile };

        private static string GetStat(XmlDocument xdocD, int id, TranTypeD tranType, StatTypeD statType)
        {
            string xpath = string.Format("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = {0}]/{1}/{2}",
                           id, tranType.ToString().ToLower(), statType.ToString().ToLower());

            return GetFirstElementText(xdocD, xpath);
        }

        // Hek
        enum TranTypeH { Buy, Sell, All };
        enum StatTypeH { Volume, Avg, Max, Min, StdDev, Median, Percentile };

        private static string GetStat(XmlDocument xdocH, int id, TranTypeH tranType, StatTypeH statType)
        {
            string xpath = string.Format("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = {0}]/{1}/{2}",
                           id, tranType.ToString().ToLower(), statType.ToString().ToLower());

            return GetFirstElementText(xdocH, xpath);
        }

        // Jita
        enum TranType { Buy, Sell, All };
        enum StatType { Volume, Avg, Max, Min, StdDev, Median, Percentile };

        private static string GetStat(XmlDocument xdoc, int id, TranType tranType, StatType statType)
        {
            string xpath = string.Format("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = {0}]/{1}/{2}",
                           id, tranType.ToString().ToLower(), statType.ToString().ToLower());

            return GetFirstElementText(xdoc, xpath);
        }
```

A picture to give you a better idea:

[image]

Comment: When you click on a value it loads the correct info or it should load the correct info?

Comment: Please explain what your expected behaviour is and remove code that isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: when i click on Dodixie the values stay the same as they are, after clicking on Hek so im my picture that's be clicking on Hek, if i click on Dodixe now the page will refresh but the values will stay the same

Comment: @Chris all this code is relevant.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `stationSelect.SelectedIndex = stationSelect.Items.IndexOf(stationSelect.Items.FindByValue("0"));
            {`

Comment: @chris that is selecting the first list item?   <asp:ListItem value="0">Jita</asp:ListItem>

Comment: is it possible that you are loading the data in your page_load event, which is overriding everything before you get to onchange?  The fix for that would be wrapping the onload initialization with if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: Why the opening brace `{` afterwards, and why are you immediately clearing the selection? You need to completely re-write this.

Comment: is it that bad i need to redo it??

Comment: @Dave nothing is loading to do with this dropdown list on page load

Comment: I agree with @ChrisPickford.  Your code doesn't make sense.  Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger so you can see what IS happening?

Comment: can you provide a good example of what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @BicPen As somebody asking for help, providing an example of what you are trying to achieve is **your** job.

Comment: @Chris your coming across with a bad attitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to change your code to:

```
protected void stationSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(stationSelect.SelectedValue == "0")
        {
            string OrePriceA = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30002187";

            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(OrePriceA);

            TriPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 34, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            TriPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 34, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            PyrPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 35, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            PyrPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 35, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            MexPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 36, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            MexPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 36, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            IsoPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 37, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            IsoPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 37, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            NocPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 38, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            NocPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 38, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            ZydPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 39, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            ZydPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 39, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            MegPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 40, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            MegPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 40, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
            MorPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 11399, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
            MorPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 11399, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
        }

        if(stationSelect.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            string OrePriceH = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30003394";

            XmlDocument xdocH = new XmlDocument();
            xdocH.Load(OrePriceH);

            TriPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 34, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            TriPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 34, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            PyrPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 35, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            PyrPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 35, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            MexPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 36, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            MexPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 36, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            IsoPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 37, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            IsoPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 37, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            NocPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 38, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            NocPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 38, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            ZydPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 39, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            ZydPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 39, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            MegPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 40, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            MegPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 40, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
            MorPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 11399, TranTypeH.Buy, StatTypeH.Max);
            MorPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocH, 11399, TranTypeH.Sell, StatTypeH.Max);
        }

        if(stationSelect.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            string OrePriceD = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30002659";

            XmlDocument xdocD = new XmlDocument();
            xdocD.Load(OrePriceD);

            TriPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 34, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            TriPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 34, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            PyrPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 35, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            PyrPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 35, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            MexPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 36, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            MexPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 36, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            IsoPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 37, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            IsoPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 37, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            NocPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 38, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            NocPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 38, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            ZydPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 39, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            ZydPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 39, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            MegPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 40, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            MegPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 40, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
            MorPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 11399, TranTypeD.Buy, StatTypeD.Max);
            MorPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdocD, 11399, TranTypeD.Sell, StatTypeD.Max);
        }
    }
```

Comment: wow that simple ay.. that worked like a charm, was gearing up my re-write my code. Any idea's on the issue with it keep defaulting to Jita when i click on say Hek?

Comment: @BicPen It shouldn't default to Jita now. It was before because you called stationSelect.ClearSelection(); on the end of the stationSelect_SelectedIndexChanged event.